# captureOutput is called prematurely

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avfoundation

In my application, I record a video while a backing track is played with The Amazing Audio Engine library.

At the end of the backing track, I stop the video recording.
Except that the `captureOutput` method is sometimes called before the end of the backing track, on the middle of it.

When it appends, my app pass in the completion block of my backing track player AFTER the call of `captureOutput` and I call `captureMovieFileOutput.stopRecording()` NOWHERE else in my code.

Here is the completion block of the backing track :

```
audioFilePlayer.completionBlock = {
                                    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
                                    captureMovieFileOutput.stopRecording()
                                    audioRecorder.finishRecording()
                                    appDelegate.audioController.removeChannels(appDelegate.audioController.channels())
                                    appDelegate.audioController.removeInputReceiver(audioRecorder)
                                    self._activityIndicator.hidden = false
                                    self._cancelButton.hidden = true
                                    self._captureSession.removeOutput(captureMovieFileOutput)
                                    self._progressView.hidden = true
                                    self._readyGoLabel.hidden = true
                                    self._recordAnimationView.hidden = true
                                    self._recordAnimationView.stopAnimation()
                                    self._restartButton.hidden = true
                                }
```

And here is the `captureOutput` function :

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) {
    if !self.view.userInteractionEnabled {
        if let audioRecordOutputURL = self._audioRecordOutputURL {
            if let videoRecordOutputURL = self._videoRecordOutputURL {
                let audioAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: audioRecordOutputURL, options: [AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey: true])
                let mutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
                let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: videoRecordOutputURL, options: [AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey: true])

                self._readyGoLabel.hidden = false

                for anyObject in videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
                    if let track = anyObject as? AVAssetTrack {
                        var error: NSError?
                        let mutableCompositionTrack: AVMutableCompositionTrack

                        if track.mediaType == AVMediaTypeVideo {
                            mutableCompositionTrack = mutableComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
                            mutableCompositionTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: kCMTimeZero, duration: track.timeRange.duration), ofTrack: track, atTime: kCMTimeZero, error: &error)
                            mutableCompositionTrack.preferredTransform = track.preferredTransform
                        }
                        if let error = error {
                            ErrorManager.defaultManager().showFatalError(title: "Error: AVFoundation", message: error.localizedFailureReason)
                        }
                    } else {
                        preconditionFailure("Fatal error: unreachable code.")
                    }
                }
                if let cizooPreviewViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(Constants.CizooPreviewViewControllerIdentifier) as? CizooPreviewViewController {
                    cizooPreviewViewController._cizoo = mutableComposition
                    cizooPreviewViewController._voiceUrl = self._audioRecordOutputURL
                    cizooPreviewViewController._recordedBackingTrack = self._backingTrack

                    self.presentViewController(cizooPreviewViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                } else {
                    preconditionFailure("Fatal error: unreachable code.")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the problem appends, In the `captureOutput` method, my app doesn't pass the condition `if !self.view.userInteractionEnabled` and error is nil.

I've seen the problem on an iPhone 4s and an iPhone 5c, and never on an iPhone 5s and 6s.

Comment: "my app doesn't pass the condition if `!self.view.userInteractionEnabled`" But why are you testing that at all? What really depends on _that_? And it has nothing whatever to do with the code you've shown so far. You have not explained how `captureOutput` ever gets called in the first place: what code calls it????

Comment: Oh sorry, `captureOutput` is a delegate method from `AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate` and it is called by `captureMovieFileOutput.stopRecording()` in my case.